# React Native blank screen at Logout Navigation on IOS only

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

In my DrawerNavigator, every routes run well except the Logout, when i touch it I only got a white blank screen on IOS (Android runs perfectly). After trying to change version of react-navigation, and look for a solution in components style,  Xcode always sends me the same error I don't find anywhere :

[This error is repeated 6 times for one touch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voqaC.png)

He are my DDrawerNavigator and my Logout code :

[DrawerNavigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyQbh.png)

[Drawer Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj3g2.png)

[Logout component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E18JP.png)

[Logout function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtAPZ.png)

[Login page style(where i should be redirected instead of blank screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK0Fi.png)

Comment: React native 0.55.4      React navigation  2.0.4    node 10.10.0    npm  6.4.1   yarn  1.9.4   Xcode 9.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally fixed the issue, the dependency react-navigation crashed the project when users logged out after updating to version 2.12.1, I 've downgraded it to 2.0.4 and it works now. If it can help help someone...